# How to select default value in drop down list using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, drop-down-menu

I want to select "Algeria" as default selected value in drop down list.I am fetching countrylist from database using handler ( LoadCountryList.ashx ) in JSON data format and binding it to dropdownlist on aspx page using Jquery's $.getJSON precedure given below

```
function AddOptions(objSelect)
{
    var URL ="~/LoadCountryList.ashx";
    $.getJSON(URL,function(countries){
        $.each(countries,function(){
            var vCountry = this['Country'];
            $(objSelect).append($("<option></option>").val(this['ID']).html(vCountry));
        });
    });
}
```

and finally i tried to set its default value "Algeria".

```
$(objSelect).find("option[text='Algeria']").attr("selected","selected"); 
OR
$(objSelect).find("option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");
```

but its not worked.Does anyone suggest me how to do it.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also i want to show waiting message like Loading... until it get complete country list from database.

Comment: couldn't you do it in the .each loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it by value, you can just use the [`val()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$(objSelect).val('3');
```

By text content, safest is to use the [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
$(objSelect).find('option').filter(function() {
    return this.text === 'Algeria';
}).attr('selected','selected');
```

---

**EDIT:** Make sure you're doing it *inside* the callback to the `getJSON()` call.

Comment: Thanks patric it worked like charm.actually i was doing this work outside getJSON() function that's why it wasn't working.thanks a lot.

Comment: one more thing i want to show waiting message like Loading... until it get complete country list from database.can u tell me how can i do that.

Comment: @Sukhi: Sure. Just decide where the message should go, then right before the `getJSON` request, do `$('#myContainer').text('loading...')` and inside the `getJSON` callback, do `$('#myContainer').text('')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(objSelect).val("Algeria");
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(objSelect).val("3");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
$(objSelect).combobox("destroy");     
$(objSelect).val("Algeria");
$(objSelect).combobox();
```

Answer (score 0):

yoy can also try this one

$(objSelect).val('1');